# Column flow with fixed number of columns?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a simple css grid https://play.tailwindcss.com/EOm6TXGpGU

```
<ul class="grid gap-1 grid-cols-2 grid-flow-row">
  <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 1</li>
  <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 2</li>
  <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 3</li>
  <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 4</li>
  <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

This example gives me wrong result:

```
Item 1 | Item 2
Item 3 | Item 4
Item 5
```

How can I make it flow columns, instead of rows?

Desired result is:

```
Item 1 | Item 4
Item 2 | Item 5
Item 3
```

Generally, I need fixed number of columns with dynamic number of rows, evenly distributed among columns. Solution with flexbox also would be fine.

Comment: I don't know tailwind, but a little tip. `.grid-flow-row` isn't the right choice, try `.grid-flow-col(umn)` or how is it named in tailwind. Just a basic logic.

Comment: with .grid-flow-col I need to specify number of rows...

Comment: This seems like a problem that would be answered better with multicolumn layout than grid.

Comment: I have a solution to this in laravel blade language. Would that be okay for you? @Molfar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul style="column-count:2;">
      <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 1</li>
      <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 2</li>
      <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 3</li>
      <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 4</li>
      <li class="bg-gray-200">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I think it's not related to tailwind , and you can dig deeper by reading this article https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-count/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="columns-2 gap-1 space-y-1">
  <li class="bg-gray-200 p-1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="bg-gray-200 p-1">Item 2</li>
  <li class="bg-gray-200 p-1">Item 3</li>
  <li class="bg-gray-200 p-1">Item 4</li>
  <li class="bg-gray-200 p-1">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/OIWCmGZlmN

Mohammed suggested the right css utility but there is also a native tailwind approach. there is a small caveat since gap-1 doesn't quite handle all the gaps so you'll need to add another space-y-1 to properly space it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).